# Get timestamp of DOB by age using mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a input "age". How do I get timestamp of DOB using mysql query ?

(eg)

```
$age = 55; // it means DOB: 14-11-1960
```

**Expected Result: 3980298496**

Note:
In PHP side, I can do like this using carbon package but it gives negative value because PHP gives negative value if date is less than Jan 1 1970

```
Carbon::now()->subYears(55)->timestamp
```

Comment: How are you meant to get their date of birth based on just their age? Unless you are assuming that everyone is born on the same day of the year?

Comment: thanks! I am not trying to find the actual DOB of user. I want the timestamp to search against sphinx. please check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33670712/php-convert-negative-time-stamp-to-positive/33674540#33674540

Comment: How did you come to 3980298496?

Comment: Yes! good question. I got this value from Sphinx which was indexed by DB expert. I just checked like this in PHP echo date('d-m-Y H:i:s', '3980298496'); it gives 12-01-1960 01:00:00

Answer (score 0):

We can use `DATE_SUB()`

Using `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL $age YEAR))) AS dob
```

Alternative way. Read [this](http://zavaboy.org/2013/01/29/alternative-for-mysql-unix_timestamp/)

```
SELECT TO_SECONDS(DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL $age YEAR)))-62167219200+TO_SECONDS(UTC_TIMESTAMP())-TO_SECONDS(NOW()) AS dob
```

Comment: thanks Subin! please change "YEARS" to "YEAR" in your above query. but it gives DOB 1960-11-14. but I need the equivalent timestamp for the DOB.

Comment: Yes but UNIX_TIMESTAMP is not works if DOB is below 1970.

Comment: http://zavaboy.org/2013/01/29/alternative-for-mysql-unix_timestamp/

I have edited the query can u check?

Comment: It's giving negative value as like PHP [strtotime('-55 years')]. this is not what I expected. thanks!

Comment: @SubinChalil Is there an update link this one referenced in your answer and the comments is broken

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED:** you can try this:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL -45 YEAR)) as DOB
```

or

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 45 YEAR)) as DOB
```

Before 1970:

try this:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF( DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL -55 YEAR),FROM_UNIXTIME(0))*24*3600
```

Comment: thanks Suchit! it gives DOB 1960-11-14. but I need the equivalent timestamp for the DOB.

Comment: yes it works If age is less than 46. because I guess, unix timestamp can not calculate if year is less than 1970.

Comment: thanks! Any other workaround to find the timestamp even DOB is below 1970 ?

Comment: @Asik try using this:`SELECT DATEDIFF(  DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL -55 YEAR),FROM_UNIXTIME(0))*24*3600`

Comment: It's giving negative value as like PHP [strtotime('-55 years')]. this is not what I expected. thanks!

Comment: @Asik then see if `SELECT DATEDIFF( FROM_UNIXTIME(0),DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL -55 YEAR))*24*3600` helps.but the negative value indicates that it is before 1970.

Comment: Yes, I got your point but my problem is

Sphinx side, users DOB stored as a different format. I am not sure that how they converted as positive timestamp. Now I am trying to filter some users based on 2 ages. (ex: 20 - 30 = works fine) (30 - 45 = works finee) (45 - 60 = not working) because of the timestamp format :) So I thought, MySQL will give a positive timestamp as like in Sphinx. otherwise, I can use PHP syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-55 years'));
```